# Libgdx pre-rendere falling objects

Tags: android, libgdx

I have an idea for a game where pre-rendered objects would fall from the sky, I would create like 20-30 objects which would look like [these](https://snag.gy/8uCiwN.jpg) 3: . But making a collision detection for all those objects would take hell of a lot of time (considering I would have to make 2-5 different shapes of collisions for each object). Is there an easy way to make them fast? Like make a texture that contains objects collision points already?

Comment: http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/physics-body-editor/

Comment: I guess you should take a look at the `box2d` physics-engine which can easily be used with libgdx. As @MennoGouw allready mentioned there is a physics-body-editor for that physics engine, which should make it easy to create complex objects.

Comment: So I would just use the physics body editor and import into my project? I heard alot about box2d, so I guess it's the same as physics body editor? We want to be able to draw textures in Photo Shop, then quickly add collision around textures and import them into game.

Comment: @pigi It takes some work but if you don't nececarely need Box2D with the body editor. The body editor spits out a Json file containing vertices of the polygon you need. Box2D has a build in importer for it but you can write your own by parsing the Json yourself. Box2D takes a lot of storage space on your final build so if you do not need it just parse the Json yourself.